# Who is this girl stuffing food in her face, and what show is it from?

Tags: kare-kano

What show is this from?

[image: this]

what exactly is happening?

I found in this [amv](http://www.animemusicvideos.org/members/members_videoinfo.php?v=87847) but the source for it (this is from boom boom dollar within that amv, at 22:04) only says "various".

Comment: Please try to upload/embed your image using our image upload service to prevent [linkrot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot). Additionally, please try to provide the time code and a link to view your video, if possible.

Comment: @Krazer I keep getting `Failed to upload image; the format is not supported` and I've never found/seen a link to view the video, only download it.

Comment: The upload tool won't work with images larger than 2MB. Normally that's far more than is necessary, but you've included a lot of redundant frames, made the size quite large, and not optimized the colors. As a result, your gif is 36MB. I've done some basic optimizations to get it down to around 500KB. While one could do better with the original source, this was enough for the purposes of uploading it with the stack.imgur account.

Comment: If you had broke the GIF into static parts it would have been better(for identification purpose) to be honest but nice job shrinking it.

Comment: @Prix FYI, you can extract static images from any GIF using websites like http://gif-explode.com/ or http://www.gifexploder.com/.

Comment: @LoganM I originally had a 3MB file, but that was too big, So I thought an online gif editor/creator could make a smaller one but I was wrong. So so wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is maybe from Kareshi Kanojo no Jijou.

> Yukino Miyazawa is a Japanese high school freshman who is the envy of classmates for her good grades and immaculate appearance. However, her "perfect" exterior is a façade, a charade she maintains to win praise. In the privacy of her own home, she is spoiled, stubborn, a slob, and studies relentlessly and obsessively to maintain her grades. On entering high school, she is knocked from her position at the top of the class by Soichiro Arima, a handsome young man whose very existence Yukino considers a threat to the praise on which she thrives, and she vows to destroy him.

[image] [image]

Seems like this could be it.

Edit: I am absolutely sure this is it as I found another image from the series. The scene occurs during episode 11.

Comment: After some searching to verify, you are correct. I still don't know what's happening because what I found was subbed in German! I'll have to find a different sub/dub. but now I know what to look for, thanks!